# Taxonomy vs. CCK List for categorizing Events

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Could someone let me know what the best practice is for choosing between implementing something as a Taxonomy vs. a List field in the Content Type?  Assuming that there is a preset list of values and there is no need for content creators to create their own.

For example, a Content Type of an "event" could be categorized based on *audience* or *type*.  Audiences can be [Kids, Youth, Adults, Seniors, etc.].  Similarly, type would have a preset list as well.

Should *audience* or *type* be created as Taxonomy or a List field in the Content Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use taxonomy, then using the calendar module they can be colour-coded in the legend based on their category.

Comment: Great point. Thank you for pointing that out.  Anything else I should consider?

Comment: Here is a writeup on the subject that I have used in the past to determine the best route for each use-case. http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/cailin/drupal-cck-vs-taxonomy